# Sort dataframe by column value (r)

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I am new to R and currently trying to wrap my head around dataframes in R.
I want to sort a dataframe by the column values, and then return the top of it after it has been sorted.

As of now I only seem to get one row back.
I used the "iris" dataframe.

```
sort <- function(df, var.name, n){
  df1 <- df[rev(order(var.name)), ]
  sorted <- head(df1, n)
  return(sorted)
}

sort_head(df = iris, var.name = "Petal.Length", n = 10)
```

```
# My output
> sort_head(df = iris, var.name = "Petal.Length", n = 5)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

My ordering of the dataframe seems to rewrite the dataframe to only contain one row - whereas all the guides (e.g [here](https://felixfan.github.io/order-sort-rank/)) I've found simply rewrites the dataframe to be sorted by column. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `df[rev(order(df$Sepal.Length)),]` will work outside the function ->

Inside the function we have to switch from `$` to `[[` and pass the function arguments as strings:

Therefore the correct term inside the function would be: `df[rev(order(df[[var.name]])), ]`

```
sort_head <- function(df, var.name, n){
    df1 <- df[rev(order(df[[var.name]])), ]
    sorted <- head(df1, n)
    return(sorted)
}

sort_head(df = iris, var.name = "Petal.Length", n = 10)
```

Output:

```
sort_head(df = iris, var.name = "Petal.Length", n = 10)
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
119          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
123          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0 virginica
118          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica
108          7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8 virginica
136          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3 virginica
131          7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9 virginica
110          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5 virginica
126          7.2         3.2          6.0         1.8 virginica
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Use `arrange()` and `slice()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
iris %>%
  arrange(desc(Petal.Length)) %>%  # arrange in descending order
  slice(1:10)                      # return rows 1 through 10
```

This returns:

```r
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
1           7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
2           7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
3           7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0 virginica
4           7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
5           7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica
6           7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8 virginica
7           7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5 virginica
8           7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9 virginica
9           7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3 virginica
10          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica
```

If you liked this approach, I highly recommend walking through the examples of [Chapter 5 of r4ds](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html) which covers `{ dplyr }`, part of `{ tidyverse }`. This is bound to save you countless hours in the future when scratching your head about data.frame transformations. =)

Comment: You may use `slice_min` or `slice_max` with `order_by` as well

Comment: Thank you Rich! I've seen that most people tend to suggest using something like dplyr and will definitely keep it in mind! I'll accept the other answer though as I think it addresses what went wrong in my code a bit more direct.

Comment: Totally! The functions @akrun mentions are also part of dplyr, which is a really flexible tool for nearly all data frame operations once you get the hang of the grammar. Best of luck!